# Which language is most suitable for an efficient web-crawler?

Tags: c#, c++

i need to write an web crawler and i need need which is best language for performance like memory and performance ..

**Edit:** Original title was "which language is optimized for speed and perfomance c++ or C#"

Comment: @Oded: What, you want someone to use a language with no object-orientated or generic programming? That's how to take six decades to write your app.

Comment: @DeadMG - He is talking about memory and performance. If you are talking about dev time, I would pick C# over C++ any time, and either one of those over C (which I would pick over assmbly).

Comment: @Marcus: The new title is a lot better. Still a silly question, though :)

Comment: Processor speed is not relevant as the bottleneck will be network throughput. So pick a language that is easy to express http connections in (javascript/php/perl)

Answer (score 7):

> i need to write an web crawler

In that case, the internet traffic is probably your bottleneck, so the language does not matter at all.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that, if you know what you're doing, C++ is more likely to be efficient than C#.

On the flip side, C# is probably easier to work with *and* to optimize your app in.

So, since you have to ask, I recommend C# in your case. ;)

Answer (score 2):

C++ virtually always offers the best performance of any language that supports modern programming techniques like generic programming and OOP. You pay a price for this though - it's substantially harder to use than C#.

Answer (score 1):

Of course C++. You can manage every byte of memory there, while C# is Managed Code, where you tell the framework what you want to do and the framework does the things you usually do in C++. But if that's the main motive - don't stop at C++ and get right to machine code, Assembly.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search would give you an instant answer - C++ is (generally) a better performing language.

Comment: Why C++ is better and C# is not better?

Comment: C++ is better C# is not better, and C# is not better because C++ is better.    All these "better" are meaningless in most cases...